# How to implement and display sentences with clickable words in R Shiny application?

Tags: r, shiny, plotly, r-plotly

I design a shiny application which one of its features is to generate new sentences (via Markov strings) from a base corpus. Let's say I generated 10 sentences, of moderate length.

```
sentences <— c(rep(c("This is a test sentence of moderate length", "This is another test sentence of moderate length"),5))
```

I would like to be able to display these sentences, one per line, quite distinctly, in my Shiny application, allowing a little interactivity. In particular, I would like the words to be clickable on a *plotly_click* model (cf *plotly* package) in order to use the clicked word as input for other manipulations.

Ideally, in an additional but secondary way, I would even like the words to be manually replaceable by the user.

I have looked into the different shiny components (shiny base, htmlwidgets, plotly etc.) without finding satisfactory solutions so far and I rely on your ideas and proposals,

Thanks a lot

Comment: What exactly do you mean with plotly_click model?

Comment: Sorry my sentence was not clear. I meant a function that looks like plotly_click: similar philiosophy and principles

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is one possible way of implementing an app just using base Shiny functions where a number of sentences are displayed, and clicking each individual word creates a new input containing just that word, which can then be used in other calculations or processes.

What I've done is manually create a load of HTML hyperlink tags wrapped around each individual word, and used the `Shiny.setInputValue` Javascript function to create a new Shiny input callable with `input$word` whenever a user clicks on a given word. To prove that a new input has been created that can be used elsewhere, I've just printed it out below the main list using `renderText` - you'll see that whenever you click on a different word, the `textOutput` updates to print the clicked word:

```
library(shiny)

ui <- fluidPage(
    uiOutput("sentences"),
    br(),br(),
    textOutput("word")
)

server <- function(input, output) {

    sentences <- c(rep(c("This is a test sentence of moderate length", "This is another test sentence of moderate length"),5))
    
    output$sentences <- renderUI({
        link_sentences <- lapply(sentences, function(x) {
            words <- unlist(strsplit(x, " ", fixed = TRUE))
            sentence <- paste0("<a href='#' onclick='Shiny.setInputValue(\"word\", \"", words, "\");'>",
                              words,
                              "</a>",
                              collapse = "",
                              sep = " ")
            HTML(paste("<br>", sentence, "</br>"))
        })
        do.call(tagList, link_sentences)
    })
    
    output$word <- renderText(input$word)
}

shinyApp(ui = ui, server = server)
```

Comment: That sounds very good to me. It's very close to what I had in mind without being able to implement it by switching to HTML directly. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

One option is to handle the sentences as a datatable

```
library(shiny)
library(DT)
library(plyr)

ui <- fluidPage(
    # Original sentences as a table
    DT::dataTableOutput('tableId'),
    # Show the selected word(s) separately 
    textOutput("text")
)

server <- function(input, output) {
    sentences <-  reactive({
        orig_sentences <- c(rep(c("This is a test sentence of moderate length", "This is another with different length"),5))
        # Split sentences on whitespace, make a table with plyr 
        t <- ldply(t(strsplit(orig_sentences, " ")), rbind)
    })

    output$tableId <- DT::renderDataTable(
        sentences(), selection = list(target = 'cell')
    )
    
    output$text <- renderText({
        # Get the selected cell(s) and get the cell value accordingly
        cell <- input$tableId_cells_selected
        sentence <- sentences()[cell]
    })
}

shinyApp(ui = ui, server = server)
```

The table is not the most pretty solution. More reader-friendly, but not that programmatically elegant way would be to have complete sentences on each cell. Selecting a cell from the sentence table could populate a new datatable with the words from the selected sentence as cells.

For the second point of your question: If you want to replace the words, you could store the sentences as `reactiveValues` and make your own replace function for storing a value from `textInput` to the selected cells .